# How to color c h and s files in dired mode?

Tags: emacs, elisp, syntax-highlighting, dired, font-lock

I would like to color source header and assembly files in the dired mode and differently.
Basically, when viewing the folder contents I want to color the files differently.
I also would like a way to color files that have a specific word in them differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using [diredful](http://www.emacswiki.org/Diredful)?

Follow the link to find a description of how to setup `diredful` and add colourisation for a file type of your choosing.

---

How to do it (You **should** read the wiki article... it even has screenshots!):

- Install `diredful` (by putting `diredful.el` somewhere in your load-path)
- add `(require 'diredful)` to your init file.
- Call `diredful-add`
- Enter name you want to give this matching pattern (e.g. `c-Files`)
- In the field `pattern` add the file name pattern to be matched, e.g. `c h`
- Under `face to use` select the face features you want to use

Comment: Thanks for the input elemakil...
I added the diredful library but I can't findout how to apply the coloring next.
Any pointers?

Comment: As I wrote above: The wiki article explains the steps. I'll add them to my answer for more clarity.

Comment: Ok. I should have made my question clearer.
I tend to include all libraries in my .emacs file.
I don't want to apply each font type using M-x diredful-add.
I want it all to be set and ready when I load emacs. I am not liking the idea of having a "saved" config file" somewhere that needs to load.

Comment: But you have another one: the ``custom.el`` file. This is the one used for customisation (aka settings) from within emacs. And that's the file to which ``diredful`` saves its customisations. This files exists by default (it may be empty if you have not done any customisations using the ``customize`` interface). Also, the process of ``diredful-add`` has to be done **once** per highlighting pattern... emacs then loads the config from your ``custom.el`` file.

Comment: elemakil...bare with me please. I am noit proficient in lisp and just a user of emacs.
I have included the full code of diredful.el in my dotemacs file.
I understood from you that I can use the function diredful-add from within emacs to start the customization of files.
Could you write one example of fontifying c files for example?

Comment: Nooo, don't do that! Emacs extensions reside in their own file (in this case ``diredful.el``) which must be placed in a folder which is registered within emacs in the variable [``load-path``](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LoadPath). Then this library is loaded into emacs using the statement ``(require 'diredful)``. These are the only two modification you should make to your ``.emacs`` file in order to get ``diredful`` up and running. The function ``diredful-add`` is called from within a running emacs and allows to add a colourisation rules using a graphical interface.

Comment: These settings are then stored (by emacs itself) in a file which is defined by the variable ``custom-file`` (see [Custon File](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CustomFile) and [Customize](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CustomizingAndSaving) for more information on how to customise emacs from within emacs. Obviously you are very new to emacs, you should read some basic tutorials one how to install, load and configure libraries! I can not help you with your question unless you understand how the overall process works.

Comment: elemakil....I am new to lisp but not to emacs.
As I mentioned I don't have separate files that include libraries.
I usually extract the code from the library file and include whatever I need from it in my .emacs file. I understand the mechanism of loading libraries from external files...I dont like that. I prefer my .emacs file to be self contained and portable by only having that file and simply move it between different platforms "mac/unix/solaris...etc".
Anyways, it seems diredful is not what I am looking for, I would like emacs to customize from within .eamcs file and not any external file

Comment: Again do **not** do that! These libraries are not intended to share the same file! This may (will!) cause problems in the future and is a pain in the neck to maintain when you update any package! Debugging becomes much more difficult. Having that said, of course, you can add the content of the ``custom-file`` to the ``.emacs`` after modifying the former using ``diredful-add``. Which is also a thing one should not do...

Comment: That was the first thing I tried actually...to include a sampled config file that resulted from diredful that I found online...did not work. I don;t think the contents of such config file are intended to be added to the dotemacs file.

Comment: Ammari: elemakil is right: it's simply not a good idea to copy libraries into your .emacs file like that, and it *can* cause you problems (e.g. lexical binding is a per-file configuration). Instead, I highly recommend putting your Emacs config files into version control, which is a much better way to maintain a portable config.

Comment: Elemakil...I finally convinced myself to start loading libraries instead of including the code in the dotemacs file...worked fine :)

Answer (score 3):

With Dired+, your file names and files extensions will use different colours.

http://wikemacs.org/index.php/Dired+

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus

And to colour files that have a specific word in their names, I don't know, but you could use Dired with wildcards:

```
  C-x d path/to/all/containing/*foo*
```

will open a Dired buffer with all files containing foo in their names.
Hope it helps !